# Is it possible to use AND in an UPDATE SET clause in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I need to check two conditions:
1. when the function returns true
2. when the function returns true AND ISP_Program has the word "IRSS" in it
What is the correct syntax? I have the following:

```
UPDATE [PAYROLL].[dbo].[BILL]
SET Pay_Code = CASE dbo.is_Holiday([BILL].Date)
                    WHEN 1 THEN holiday_code
                    WHEN 1 AND ISP_Program like '%IRSS%' THEN '66'
                    ELSE Pay_Code
                END 
FROM tbl_TXEX_HOLIDAY
INNER JOIN [BILL] ON [BILL].Pay_Code = tbl_HOLIDAY.regular_code
```

Comment: Your second condition is a subset of the first.  Sample data and desired results might clarify what you want.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: You've tried to mix a _simple case_ and a _searched case_ expression. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types) explains the difference in conditions. And `'1'` is not a [`boolean data type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#boolean-data-type) value suitable for use with [`and`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SET Pay_Code = (CASE WHEN dbo.is_Holiday([BILL].Date) = 1 AND ISP_Program like '%IRSS%' THEN '66'
                    WHEN dbo.is_Holiday([BILL].Date) = 1 THEN holiday_code
                    ELSE Pay_Code
                END)
```

Note that the ordering of these conditions is important.

I assume that `BILL` is the table referenced in the `UPDATE`.  I would recommend writing the complete logic as:

```
UPDATE b
    SET Pay_Code = (CASE WHEN dbo.is_Holiday(b.Date) = 1 AND ISP_Program like '%IRSS%' THEN '66'
                         WHEN dbo.is_Holiday(b.Date) = 1 THEN holiday_code
                         ELSE b.Pay_Code
                    END)  
    FROM [PAYROLL].[dbo].[BILL] b JOIN
         tbl_TXEX_HOLIDAY h
         ON b.Pay_Code = h.regular_code;
```

Notes:

- Define aliases for the tables so the query is easier to write and to read.
- Use the `alias` for the update, so it is clear what you intend.
- Put the table being updated first.  After all, it needs to have matching rows for the `update` to take place.
- Of course, fix the `case` expression.

Comment: You are right in assuming the BILL table is the one referenced in the UPDATE. I will go ahead and make aliases and change the query to put the table being updated first and fix the CASE statement. Thank you!